# jQuery PNG transition with alpha

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png

ive got a problem, ive been researching for like 1 month already and nothing worked.

Ive got a Image Slider with jQuery, and when there is a transition the alpha on images get black colored, i know Internt explorer just supports one alpha at the moment and thats why im getting this error, but id like to know if there is any solution

the site is : http://www.posavasos.pe/kontiki , at the moment im using images with out alpha thats why the borders look buggy

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 6 and below do not support alpha channel properly, as you already stated. Unfortunately there is no fix that will work in the scenario in which you are trying to apply it, given the complexities involved.

Given that IE6 is in significantly less use today, my best recommendation would be to abandon attempts at making your site backward compatible "that far," and rather provide a message on your site to users who have IE6 that says something along the lines of "This web page was designed for use with Internet Explorer 7 or better. Please update ..." etc. and provide update and alternative browser links to Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and 8 do support transparent pngs, but it breaks if you apply a opacity to them. I'm not sure about IE9, but since it has native opacity support, it might work.

The only solution I know is to nest two divs with the image sizes. Use the [old filter syntax](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6) to apply the image as a background to the inner div, then apply the alpha to the outer div.

It is possible to use just one div, but libs like jQuery do not support multiple filters (and IE7/8 require you to set a filter for opacity and one for the image).